# Перебор двойного массива

Tags: java

Задан двойной массив в котором по рандомно появляется единица. Необходимо изменить на единицу все значения справа от единицы за один раз можно менять только одно значение. Моя проблема в том что цикл меняет правое значение на 1 и меняет правое от него. Возможно ли сделать так что бы цикл сначала нашел все единицы в массиве а потом поменял значение справа от них на 1? Целью задания является узнать за сколько повторений цикл заполнит необходимые элементы.

```
 int h = 1;
    while (h < 5) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                    if (j < (M - 1)) {
                        array[i][j + 1] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        h++;
    }
```

Comment: Если массив двойной, зачем вам первый цикл с какой-то переменной `h`? И что за переменная `M`? Вам нужно сделать ещё один цикл, который будет запускаться в случае, если `array[i][j] == 1` и менять все последующие значения на 1.

Answer (score 0):

Во внутреннем цикле обходи справа налево и смотри налево, тогда не будешь "наступать" на только что измененный элемент.

```
    int[] arr = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 0};
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i - 1] == 1)
            arr[i] = 1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```